# the "simplest" spherical metric of an arbitrary Riemannian 3-manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 3d, spherical-coordinates, diffeomorphism

In spherical coordinates, the metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (Euclidean space) has the following nice properties:

- $g_{rr}$ is independent of $r$, $\theta$ and $\phi$
- $g_{\theta\theta}$ is independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$
- $g_{\phi\phi}$ is independent of $\phi$
- $g_{r\theta} = g_{r\phi} = g_{\theta\phi} = 0$

That's 3 components of the metric, and 6 partial derivatives, that are zero.  Pretty convenient to work with!

So what about a general Riemannian 3-manifold that is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ **but has curvature**?  How many of those 9 conditions can we enforce simultaneously, by choosing just the right "spherical" coordinate system?

For example, once we pick an origin, can we claim that the geodesics emanating from the origin will never intersect each other?  In that case, we could make them our $r$ coordinate lines, have $g_{rr}$ measure true distance, and thus satisfy the first point: $g_{rr,r} = g_{rr,\theta} = g_{rr,\phi} = 0$.  And wouldn't that also imply $g_{r\theta} = g_{r\phi} = 0$?

And is it possible to do this in such a way that **at least one of** $g_{\theta\phi}$, $g_{\theta\theta,\theta}$, $g_{\theta\theta,\phi}$, and $g_{\phi\phi,\phi}$ also vanish globally?  How many could we get?

Comment: In general, distinct geodesics emanating from the origin will intersect again.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your $\mathbb R^3$ hypothesis. The local behavior of arbitrary Riemannian metrics on arbitrary 3-manifolds is identical to the local behavior of arbitrary Riemannian metrics on $\mathbb R^3$: for any point $x$ on any 3-manifold $M$ equipped with any Riemannian metric $g$, choose $f : U \to \mathbb R^3$ to be a diffeomorphism defined on some neighborhood $U$ of $x$, and put the metric $f_*(g)$ on $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Well that certainly puts a damper on things.  Thank you for pointing that out.  Silly wishful thinking on my part, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about intrinsic properties of a given metric (regarding this: your example with spherical coordinates on $\mathbb R^3$ does NOT define a curved metric) or about properties of specific coordinate systems? For standard metric on $\mathbb R^3$ you can of course have all components of metric constant, just use cartesian coordinates. For more general metrics this is usually not possible because there is an obstruction given by the curvature tensor (if metric components are constant in some coordinate system, then curvature tensor vanishes, but of course there exist metrics with nonzero curvature tensor).

Comment: But the flatness of the metric in spherical coordinates imposes a bunch of partial differential equations here that need not hold in general. A cursory computation says you can get metrics with nonconstant curvature out of this setup.

Comment: I'm using $R^3$ as a reference, but I want to know for an *arbitrary* curved 3d manifold $M$ that has the same topology as $R^3$, *and* I specifically want to use spherical coordinates on $M$, ie. have an $r$ coordinate relative to some origin.  Basically, I just want to know if it's always possible to choose this coordinate system on $M$ such that certain components and derivatives of the metric vanish globally.  I'll try to update the question accordingly.